# An inequality involving supremum and integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

Let $g$ be a positive function defined on $(0,\infty)$. Is the following inequality always true ?
$$
\sup_{r<t<\infty}g(t)\leq C\int_{r}^{\infty}g(t)\frac{dt}{t},
$$
where positive constant $C$ does not depend on $r>0$.

Comment: We should assume something more (integrability? square-integrability?) on $g$ to give that question a sense. If $g$ is constantly $1$, the LHS is $1$ and the RHS does not even exist.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio thanks for your comment. We assume that $\int_{r}^{\infty}g(t)\frac{dt}{t}<\infty$ for all $r>0$. In that case what can we say about this inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. We may just consider a positive function $f(t)=\frac{g(t)}{t}$ that belongs to $L^1\setminus L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^+)$ and is unbounded on every interval $(r,+\infty)$, like:
$$ f(t) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\mathbb{1}_{(n,n+1)}(t)}{2^n\sqrt{t-n}}.$$
We have:
$$ \| f \|_1 = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{2}{2^n} = 4 $$
but for every $r\in\mathbb{R}^+$ we have $\sup_{t>r}f(t) = +\infty$, so $\sup_{t>r}g(t)=\sup_{t>r}t\cdot f(t) = +\infty$, too.

A similar counter-example is given by taking $h(x)=\frac{e^{-|x|}}{\sqrt{|x|}}$ and $f(t)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{h(t-n)}{2^n}.$

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I have questions about your counter example $ f(t) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\mathbb{1}_{(n,n+1)}(t)}{2^n\sqrt{t-n}}.$  I can't show the unboundedness of $f$ on every interval $(r,+\infty)$ and how does $\sup_{t>r}f(t) = +\infty$ imply the $\sup_{t>r}g(t) = +\infty$. Because $\sup_{t>r}g(t)=\sup_{t>r}t\cdot f(t) \leq \sup_{t>r}t\cdot\sup_{t>r}f(t)=+\infty$.

Comment: @bjk1806: that's pretty trivial - $f$is positive, hence for any $t>1$ we have $t\cdot f(t)>f(t)$, so if $f$ is unbounded, $t\cdot f(t)$ is unbounded too.

Comment: And about the first part, if $h$ is supported on $I=(0,1)$, it is integrable and unbounded on $I$, then $\sum_{n\geq 0}2^{-n}\,h(x-n)$ is integrable and unbounded on $\mathbb{R}^+$, obviously.

Comment: thank you very much for your big help.

Comment: If we add one more hypothesis, that is if we assume that
$\sup_{r<t<\infty}g(t)<\infty$ and $\int_{r}^{\infty}g(t)\frac{dt}{t}<\infty$ for all $r>0$, what can we say about this inequality ?

Comment: I found the following lemma: "Let $g:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}^+$. If there is a constant $c>0$ such that for any $r>0$: $\int_{r}^{\infty}g(t)\frac{dt}{t}\leq c g(r)$, then there are constants $\varepsilon>0$ and $C>0$ such that for any $r>0$: $\int_{r}^{\infty}t^{\varepsilon}g(t)\frac{dt}{t}\leq C g(r)r^{\varepsilon}$". Would that lemma be helpful ?

Comment: @bjk1806: that is a different matter, it would be better to post it as a separate question and maybe link this one as a reference for something similar.