# An inequality involving supremum and integral 2

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

In the following post [An inequality involving supremum and integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382979/an-inequality-involving-supremum-and-integral/1383151?noredirect=1#comment2818614_1383151), there was discussed the inequality 
$$
\sup_{r<t<\infty}g(t)\leq C\int_{r}^{\infty}g(t)\frac{dt}{t},
$$
where positive constant $C$ does not depend on $r>0$ and $g$ is a positive function defined on $(0,\infty)$ under the hypothesis $\int_{r}^{\infty}g(t)\frac{dt}{t}<\infty$ for all $r>0$. I wonder that under the hypotheses "$\int_{r}^{\infty}g(t)\frac{dt}{t}<\infty$ and $\sup_{r<t<\infty}g(t)<\infty$ for all $r>0$" what can we say about this inequality?

Comment: @Tryss We don't know the mentioned inequality true or not. How can we  say that $\int_{r}^{\infty}g(t)\frac{dt}{t}<\infty$ implies that $\sup_{r<t<\infty}g(t)<\infty$? There was examples in mentioned post such that  $\int_{r}^{\infty}g(t)\frac{dt}{t}<\infty$ and $\sup_{r<t<\infty}g(t)=\infty$.

Comment: What if you cut such exemples at an arbitrary height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take

$$g(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{1}_{[n,n+2^{-n}]} (t)$$

You have that

$$\sup_{r<t<\infty} g(t) =1< \infty$$

Indeed, the $[n,n+2^{-n}]$ are disjoints, so $t$ is at most in one interval $[n,n+2^{-n}]$. This means that either $g(t) = 0$ (if $t$ is not in one of such intervals) or $g(t) = 1$ (if $t$ is in one of such intervals)

But for $r >1$, as $g(t)\geq 0$, you have

$$0 < \int_r^\infty \frac{g(t)}{t} dt \leq  \int_{\lfloor r \rfloor}^\infty \frac{g(t)}{t} dt \leq \int_{\lfloor r \rfloor}^\infty g(t) dt $$

$$ \leq \int_{\lfloor r \rfloor}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{1}_{[n,n+2^{-n}]} (t) dt \leq \sum_{n=\lfloor r \rfloor}^\infty \mu([n,n+2^{-n}]) $$

$$ \leq \sum_{n=\lfloor r \rfloor}^\infty 2^{-n} = 2^{1-\lfloor r \rfloor}$$

Now, let $r\to +\infty$, you get

$$\lim_{r\to +\infty} \int_r^\infty \frac{g(t)}{t} dt =0$$
So clearly, you can't have a $C$ independant of $r$ such that

$$\sup_{r<t<\infty} g(t) \leq  C \int_r^\infty \frac{g(t)}{t} dt$$

If this was true, you would get, by taking $r$ to infinity,

$$1\leq 0$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i can't see how do you obtain $\sup_{r<t<\infty} g(t) =1$ and $ \int_r^\infty \frac{g(t)}{t} dt \leq  2^{1-\lfloor r\rfloor}$ ? can you write these facts with more details?

Comment: @bjk1806 : done. Note that this show that it's impossible when $r$ get big, one may only be interested for when $r$ get small